# react native how to filter JSON

Tags: json, react-native

This is my local JSON file (JsonData.json):

```
{
  "Phone": [
    {
      "num": "phone1",
      "name": "galaxy",
      "temp": [
        "5",
        "6"
      ],
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "num": "phone2",
      "name": "iPhone",
      "temp": [
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
      ],
      "id": 2
    },
  …
  ],

  "Computer": [
    {
      "num": "computer1",
      "name": "Mac",
      "temp": [
        "1"
      ],
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "num": "computer2",
      "name": "Samsung",
      "temp": [
        "4"
      ],
      "id": 2
    },
  …
  ]
}
```

And I imported it this way (I've been correctly using it):

```
var JsonData = require('./JsonData.json');
```

I want to get a name (galaxy, iPhone...) when `temp = "4"`, from both phone and computer data.

How can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const newArray = [...JsonData["Phone"], ...JsonData["Computer"]];
const result = newArray.filter(item => {
  if(item.temp.indexOf("4") !== -1) return item.name;
});
```

The result will be: ["iPhone", "Samsung"].

Comment: Thank you! By the Way, I tried to print out the result like this, <Text style={styles.title}>{result}</Text> But ran into this error. "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child(found:object with keys)". Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to parse the JSON

```
function loopObj(value, array){
    let keyList = Object.keys(array)
    var namesArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       let arrayVal = a[keys[i]];
       for (var j = 0; j < arrayVal.length; j++) {
          var innerArray = arrayVal[j]
          if (innerArray.temp.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
              namesArray.push(innerArray.name)
          }
       }
    }
   return(namesArray)
}

loopObj("4", a) // will give you the array ["iPhone", "Samsung"]
```